# How to open all folders in one click in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app, workflow, plugin

I'm tired of opening a tree of subfolders. I want to open all folders in a Layer List panel in one click. Is there a Sketch plugin or any other way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Holding ⌥ option key** and clicking on the expand arrow beside folder icon in the layer list panel will open all subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

You can open all nested layer groups by selecting the parent group and pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>. You can find additional options for the layer list under `View > Layerlist` in the system menu bar.

Comment: It doesn't;t open all nested layers, just the top one in a nested layer tree. I have to repeat this command on every layer manually

Comment: You can select all groups then press the hotkey, or you can nest all groups inside a singular master parent-group, then run the command.